# Should meteor helpers always be functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

Do meteor helpers have to be functions? I thought they could be assigned directly to anything that spacebars could understand (arrays, strings, numbers, etc). But this isn't working correctly:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers = ({
    'tabButtons': [{
        title: "Active Topics",
        link: "/dashboard/topic-builder/active",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-6",
        active: isActive("activeTopics", Template.currentData())
    }, {
        title: "Draft Topics",
        link: "/dashboard/topic-builder/drafts",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-6",
        active: isActive("draftTopics", Template.currentData())
    }]
}
```

By "Not working correctly", I mean "tabButtons" is undefined in `myTemplate`. This, however, works fine:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers = ({
    'tabButtons': function(){
        return [{
            title: "Active Topics",
            link: "/dashboard/topic-builder/active",
            bootstrap: "col-xs-6",
            active: isActive("activeTopics", Template.currentData())
        }, {
            title: "Draft Topics",
            link: "/dashboard/topic-builder/drafts",
            bootstrap: "col-xs-6",
            active: isActive("draftTopics", Template.currentData())
    }];
}
```

What's weird is that this same syntax IS working elsewhere in my code. For example, this:

```
Template.myTemplate2.helpers({

    'sectionButtons': [{
        title: "Matrix",
        icon: "fa-table",
        link: "/dashboard/overview",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-2"
    }, {
        title: "Topic Builder",
        icon: "fa-database",
        link: "/dashboard/topic-builder",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-2"
    }, {
        title: "Alerts",
        icon: "fa-exclamation-circle",
        link: "/dashboard/alerts",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-2"
    }, {
        title: "Story",
        icon: "fa-book",
        link: "/dashboard/story-of-the-day",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-2"
    }, {
        title: "Add Admin",
        icon: "fa-plus",
        link: "/dashboard/addadmin",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-2"
    }, {
        title: "Settings",
        icon: "fa-cog",
        link: "/dashboard/settings",
        bootstrap: "col-xs-2"
    }]

});
```

Is NOT undefined in `myTemplate2`. I've checked for global helpers with the same name and things passed to each context with the same name, just to make sure something else wasn't returning undefined and overriding my function, but that's definitely not what's causing the problem.

What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was with `Template.currentData()`, not the fact that I was using a function. For example, this:

```
'tabButtons': [{
    title: "Active Topics",
    link: "/dashboard/topic-builder/active",
    bootstrap: "col-xs-6",
    active: isActive("activeTopics", "activeTopics")
}, {
    title: "Draft Topics",
    link: "/dashboard/topic-builder/drafts",
    bootstrap: "col-xs-6",
    active: isActive("draftTopics", "draftTopics")
}]
```

works fine.

When I was assigning the array directly, I thought `Template.currentData()` would work because it was defined within a helper. But it appears that both using `template.data` and `Template.currentData()` only work when defined in a function directly passed to a helper. That makes sense, now that I think about it, as there is no way to modify the context where `tabButtons` is defined, since the line where I included `Template.currentData()` would have been executed before it was even passed to `Template.topicBuilder.helpers`.